# Issue with configuring web.config to use sql server database

Tags: web-config, breeze, hottowel

I playing around with the John Papa's HotTowel application.  The HotTowel sample uses local codecamper.sdf database and I am trying to configure it to use the database on a sql server 2008 r2. When I run the application, I am getting an error saying "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.dll but was not handled in user code." The error is occurring in the CodeCamperRepository.cs on the line that says "get {return _contextProvider.Metadata()" code. The inner exception says

```
The connection string 'CodeCamper' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute."
```

I have the following code in web.config, but I unsure if it is correct:

```
<configuration>
      <configSections>
            <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
       </configSections>
       <connectionStrings>
          <add name="CodeCamper" connectionString="Data Source=testdb\cmstest; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.web>
          <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
          <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.web>
      <entityFramework>
          <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
               <parameter value="Data Source=testdb\cmstest; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
          <providers>
             <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
        </entityFramework>
        <system.webServer>
          <handlers>
              <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
              <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
              <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
              <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
          </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
      </configuration>
```

Are there any other changes I should look at to make HotTowel connect to Sql Server? what is it that breeze doesn't like about the configuration?  Appreciate any insight.

thanks Community
np

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like the inner exception says: you need the `providerName` attribute.  So change your ConnectionStrings section to:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CodeCamper" connectionString="Data Source=testdb\cmstest; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Yeh, I tried that too, just before you posted. Now it is wining about it not liking the data source

Comment: The new message I get is An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

Comment: That error might be from the parameters in the `defaultConnectionFactory` section.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking, but do you have the CodeCamper connection reference in your DbContext contstructor?

```
public CCDbContext()
        : base("CodeCamper"){ }
```

Comment: yes I do. Here is the code I have in the CodeCamperDbContext.cs  `namespace CC.DataAccess
    {
        public class CodeCamperDbContext : DbContext' 
        {
            public CodeCamperDbContext()
                : base(nameOrConnectionString: "CodeCamper") { }`

Comment: sorry about the code not formatted right.  I indenting 4 spaces but it's not displaying code in a block.